# Value error: list.remove(x) x not in list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have to figure out the lowest score and then remove it from the list. Here's my code:

```
n = int(input())
list = []
for i in range(n+1):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    list.append([name,score])
print(list)

min_scores = list[0][1]
for x in list:
  if (x[1]<float(min_scores)):
    min_scores = x[1]
  list.remove(min_scores)
print(list)
```

Error msg reads

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-44e6d871c75e> in <module>
     11     if (x[1]<float(min_scores)):
     12         min_scores = x[1]
---> 13     list.remove(min_scores)
     14 print(list)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: You wat to find the lowest integer in a list?

Comment: you append a list and try to remove a number. Store `min_x` and remove `min_x` instead. Or sort your list of list by the score and slice it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the builtin `min` function with the proper key function and pass this as an argument to `remove`.

```
n = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(n+1):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    lst.append([name, score])
    
lst.remove(min(lst, key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

Also don't use builtin types as variable names (list is not a keyword as other answers say).

Answer (score 0):

You made a critical error, Never use a keyword as a variable name.
And I hope this code snippet will be help for you.

```py
n = int(input())
lst = []  # never use a keyword as a variable name
for i in range(n+1):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    lst.append([name,score])

print(lst)

min_score = [] 
for x, y in lst:  # use two variables because lst is a 2 dimential array
    min_score.append(y)  # adding y into min_score list


min_score.sort() # sorting min_score
del(min_score[0]) #  after sorting first value of array will be minimum, so remove it.

print(min_score)
```

Comment: I see what you're doing but I forgot to mention in my query that i want to retain the structure of the list as it is. You have created a new list which captures all the scores, sorts them ascending and then deletes the first entry. But this list doesn't have names alongside, I wanted the names too and the next stage of my code demands that the names be arranged alphabetically for equal scores. But anyways thanks a lot, appreciate you taking the effort of writing the code and that too with comments:):) Love this space, love the peeps, always ready to help

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
listOfScores = []

for i in range(n + 1):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    listOfScores.append([name, score])

print(listOfScores)

minScoreList = listOfScores[0]

for x in listOfScores:
    if x[1] < float(minScoreList[1]):
        minScoreList = x
listOfScores.remove(minScoreList)

print(listOfScores)
```

Answer (score 0):

To honest this is called trash code in programmers community. If you need algorithm

to figure out the lowest score and then remove it from the list. Then do it like this

```
scores_list = []


def get_scores():
    print('Type "stop" to stop the program')
    x = input('Enter score:')
    if x.isdigit():
        scores_list.append(x)
    if x == 'stop':
        return print('Minimum score is:', min(scores_list))

    get_scores()


get_scores()
```

And to note: Never use keywords in variable names further it may lead to the incorrect work of your program